# How do you prove a presence of GAN generated samples being exactly (or almost exactly) identical to real observations?

Tags: machine-learning, proof-assistants

Suppose that $X\in\mathcal{X}$ is data in abstract space and $Z\in\mathcal{Z}$ is random noise vectors in latent space over a defined prior $P(Z)$ (e.g., Gaussian).

Then, let $G$ and $D$ denote generator and discriminator. In a generative adversarial network (GAN), we train $G$ to generate samples $G(Z)$ through adversarial process (i.e., **implicit learning**) against $D$, in that distribution of the generated samples is as analogous to the distribution of the real data as possible; $P_G(X) \approx P_{real}(X)$. Now, I also define an inverse mapping (of $G$) $F:\mathcal{X}\to \mathcal{Z}$ which is trained **only** **on the generated samples** $G(Z)$.

Now, what things should I prove if I want to claim that "From GAN training if $P_G(X) \approx P_{real}(X)$ was achieved, there should exist at least one generated sample that is identical or almost identical to a real observation as in $G(Z)\cap (X\sim P_{real}(X)) \neq \varnothing$ such that for some $X\sim P_{real}(X)$ I have $X\approx G(F(X))$".

Suggesting any related papers or proof would be very helpful!

I do not have plain math skills and commuter science background, so if I have made anything incorrect above please correct me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion D.W.. I edited the question based on your suggestion now.

Comment: Please define what it means for a sample to be "almost identical to a real observation".  Also your "there should exist" statement still has the problem that the statement after the "such that" does not depend on the variable, i.e., it has the form $\exists w. \varphi$ where $\varphi$ does not depend on $w$, which seems like it can't be right.  The first step to proving something is to carefully formulate the claim you are trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you D.W. for your feedback again! I made another modification on the question. Any further feedbacks would be very appreciated!